# How to list pending route53 requests via AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-cli

The [route53domains console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home?#DomainRequests:) can show list of pending domain transfers/purchases but I didn't find a way to get this information from the AWS CLI "[route53domains](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53domains/index.html)" subcommand. Is this possible?

Comment: [list-operations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53domains/list-operations.html)? Not posting this as an answer because I can't confirm it, but it _looks_ correct…

Comment: It showed me only last three or so operations which were domain updates to point to new hosted zones and domain contact changes. It might do the trick if I had the operation ID but I didn't find a way to obtain it.